# Ajax will not send data further and therefore presents an error in consol.log

Tags: javascript, ajax

It's like when I click it to pay, Stripe pop up and when I click pay now. Then it comes forward and tells

> POST http://localhost:58712/api/Stripe 500 (Internal Server Error)

When I look into console, I'm telling me that my lineJS.js is in error on line 31. That is, it's my `$.ajaz ({` which causes problems.

The question is so from here.

How could it be that it causes problems?

My jquery CDN is at the top of the page same with my call to Stripe Check out.

How could it be that it does not cause it to send that data?

```
console.log("test")

function PayStripe() {
    // Open Checkout with further options:
    handler.open({
        name: 'Hello World',
        description: 'Test Site',
        currency: "dkk",
        amount: $('#HiddenPrice').val() * 100,
        email: $('#Email').val()
    });
};

// Close Checkout on page navigation:
$(window).on('popstate', function () {
    handler.close();
});

var handler = StripeCheckout.configure({
    key: 'pk_test_xxxxxxxxxx',
    locale: 'auto',
    token: function (token) {
        token.subscriptionId = $('#HiddenIdMedlemskab').val();
        token.userId = $('#hiddenUserId').val();
        //ERROR FROM HERE!!
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "./api/Stripe",
            contentType: "application/json",
            data: token,
            success: function (data) {
                window.location.href = './Subscriptions/Succes';
                console.log("succes")
            },
            error: function (data) {
                //SEND THIS HERE.
                console.log("Error")
            },
            dataType: 'json'
        });
        // You can access the token ID with `token.id`.
        // Get the token ID to your server-side code for use.
    }
});
```

Comment: HTTP 500 means it's the server side that has crashed, nothing to do with your JS client side code.

Comment: What u mean ?? @zerkms

Comment: What part of *"server side crashed"* isn't clear? Your back end code threw an exception while making the request

Comment: It means the endpoint called through the ajax request failed to execute whatever it was suppose to do.

Comment: What I want to do is by sending some data to the API. @lealceldeiro

Comment: That's the way I've moved the entire MVC my old side over to .net core 2.0. @charlietfl So I do not think it should give so many problems.

Comment: Check your error logs. Something failed enough to go to a `500 (Internal Server Error)`

Comment: Note you aren't sending json to server. If you are expecting json there try `data: JSON.stringify(token),`

Comment: it's not work... @charlietfl